# optimization/alternative for css background image animation

Tags: javascript, css, webgl, css-animations

I need to have a full page background image, slowly panning from right to left and repeating itself infinitely. Here is my css:

```css
#animatedBackground {
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  will-change: transform;
/* transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmL0s.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  animation: animatedBackground 1000s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animatedBackground {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -10000px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="animatedBackground"></div>
```

I work on a macbook pro retina 2015. My problem is that in chrome and firefox, my CPU usage rises to 100%, bit less when i reduce the size of the window. I implemented the "transform: translateZ(0)" and the "will-change: transform" but these don't seem to have much effect. Surprisingly, in safari it seems to be handled by the GPU. The image is quite big but I cannot reduce the quality. Is there a better alternative to CSS animation for my case? Preferably vanilla JS or webgl?

Secondly, this code makes the animation work for a thousand seconds then there is a glitch. Is there a way to make it properly endless?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you set up an example with a real image with similar dimensions as the one you are having problems with?

Comment: here it is : http://scratchpad.io/ruthless-men-1910

Comment: In the example, the animation is not infinite but will turn white after a while, is this intentional? In my example, I made it infinite now, but if you prefer I can also change it to being finite.

Comment: that's funny, I get the exact opposite result, my code shows seamless animation where yours end up with white space before looping. Actually I need to find out a way to make it truly endless: I edited my question.

Answer (score 3):

The problem comes from `background-position` - this will be rendered by the cpu in some cases.
If you adjust this to use transform by adding a placeholder element in your div, the performance should improve:

https://jsfiddle.net/kofn5dyr/27/

The basic idea:
Instead of animating the background position, add a wrapper inside your first div.
Animate this wrapper using transform, as transform will be handled by the gpu.

```css
#animatedBackground {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

#animatedBackground > div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 2526px;
  background: url(https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/4643298-images.jpg);
  background-size: contain;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  animation: moveSlideshow 12s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes moveSlideshow {
  100% { 
    transform: translateX(-66.6666%);   
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="animatedBackground">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

I adjusted the example a bit with an image where the animation is more obivious, please adjust all example values as you need them in your project.
Maybe also add browser prefixes as you need them.